# Showing context menu scrolls up the parent container

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, tailwind-css

I'm setting up a chat application with the UI code below:

```
export default function Chat({
    setSourceText,
    createNewTab,
    handleChatError,
    setChatError,
}) {
    
    ...
    ...

    useLayoutEffect(() => {
        // Scroll the container element to the bottom
        if (messagesContainerRef.current) {
            messagesContainerRef.current.scrollTop =
                messagesContainerRef.current.scrollHeight;
        }
    }, [messages]);
 
    return (
        <div className="relative h-full w-full transition-width flex flex-col overflow-hidden items-stretch flex-1">
            <div
                ref={messagesContainerRef}
                className="flex flex-col text-sm overflow-y-auto"
            >
                {messages.map((message, index) => {
                    return (
                        <div key={index}>
                            <div className="group h-auto overflow-hidden text-black w-full px-4 py-2 text-justify tracking-wide leading-loose text-sm">
                                {message.input}
                            </div>
                            <div className="group h-auto text-black overflow-hidden w-full bg-gray-100 px-4 py-2 text-justify tracking-wide leading-loose text-sm">
                                <ChatResponse
                                    response={message.response}
                                    handleSubmitSources={handleSubmitSources}
                                    createNewTab={createNewTab}
                                    sources={message.sources}
                                    collectionName={collectionName}
                                    handleChatError={handleChatError}
                                />
                                <ChatSources
                                    sources={message.sources}
                                    setSourceText={setSourceText}
                                    collectionName={collectionName}
                                    createNewTab={createNewTab}
                                />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    );
                })}
            
                ...
                ...
                
                <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                    <textarea
                        value={input}
                        ref={textAreaRef}
                        onChange={handleChange}
                        disabled={isInputDisabled}
                        onKeyDown={(event) => {
                            if (event.key === "Enter" && !event.shiftKey) {
                                handleSubmit(event);
                            }
                        }}
                        id="input"
                        name="input"
                        type="text"
                        placeholder="Type your question here..."
                        required
                        rows={1}
                        className="block w-full h-auto max-h-48 text-black resize-none overflow-y-auto appearance-none rounded-md border border-gray-300 px-3 py-2 placeholder-gray-400 shadow-sm focus:border-indigo-500 focus:outline-none focus:ring-indigo-500 sm:text-sm"
                    />
                </form>
                <button
                    className="absolute bottom-5 right-2 pr-2 transform -rotate-45"
                    onClick={handleSubmit}
                >
                    <PaperAirplaneIcon className="h-5 w-6 text-gray-500" />
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
```

`ChatResponse` has the code for showing the context menu:

```
function ChatResponse({
    response,
    handleSubmitSources,
    createNewTab,
    sources,
    collectionName,
    handleChatError,
}) {
    const [contextMenu, setContextMenu] = useState(null);
    const selectedTextRef = useRef(null);

    const handleContextMenu = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();

        const selectedText = window.getSelection().toString();

        // If some text is selected
        if (selectedText) {
            selectedTextRef.current = selectedText;
            setContextMenu(
                contextMenu === null
                    ? { mouseX: event.clientX + 2, mouseY: event.clientY - 6 } : null
            );
        }
    };

    const handleClose = () => {
        selectedTextRef.current = null;
        setContextMenu(null);
    };
    
    return (
        <div>
            <div
                onContextMenu={handleContextMenu}
                //className={contextMenu ? "bg-blue-100" : ""}
            >
                <ResponseText
                    response={response}
                    selectedText={selectedTextRef.current}
                />
            </div>
            <Menu
                className="absolute"
                open={contextMenu !== null}
                onClose={handleClose}
                anchorReference="anchorPosition"
                anchorPosition={
                    contextMenu !== null
                        ? { top: contextMenu.mouseY, left: contextMenu.mouseX }
                        : undefined
                }
            >
                <MenuItem> Item 1 </MenuItem>
                <MenuItem> Item 2 </MenuItem>
            </Menu>
        </div>
    );
}
```

However, when there are a lot of messages, which causes the `messages.map` UI to automatically scroll down, opening up the context menu will scroll up to the start of the `messages.map` UI which isn't good UX. How do I fix this? I mainly used `tailwind` for styling but the `Menu` and `MenuItem` components are from `material`